# Is the space of vectorial functions that are Dunford integrable complete?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, integration

Let $X$ a Banach Space and $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ a measure space. A function $F:\Omega\rightarrow X$ is Dunford integrable if $x^\ast\circ F$ is $\mu$-integrable for every $x^\ast\in X^\ast$. The space of functions that are Dunford integrable, denoted by $\mathbb{D}(\mu,X)$, is a normed space with
$$
  \|F\|:=\sup\left\{\int_\Omega|x^\ast\circ F|d\mu:x^\ast\in X^\ast,\,\|x^\ast\|\leq1\right\}
$$
Does anybody knows if the space $\mathbb{D}(\mu,X)$ is complete?

Comment: Is there any obstacle when trying the usual proof that e.g. $L^1(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ is complete?

Comment: The usual proof doesn't work in this case, because we consider vectorial functions, and the norm depends on the functionals $x^\ast$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This a revised and expanded version of my post.*

**No**, it is not complete. For simplicity suppose that $X$ is reflexive and separable in which case Dunford and Pettis integrals coincide. Suppose also that $\mu$ is finite and non-atomic. In this case the space of Pettis integrable functions is complete if and only if $X$ is finite-dimensional as proved by Thomas

> G.E.F. Thomas, *Totally Summable Functions with Values in Locally Convex Spaces*,
>   Measure Theory (Oberwolfach 1975), Lecture Notes in Math. Vol. **541** (1976), 117–131.

This is based on a result o his which asserts that there exist an absolutely sequence summable sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $X$ (reflexivity is not needed) and a sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in the unit ball of $L_1(\mu)$ such that the vector measure

$$\nu(A) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int\limits_A f_n(t)\,{\rm dt}\cdot x_n$$

does not have a Pettis intregrable density.

> G.E.F. Thomas, The Lebesgue-Nikodym Theorem for Vector Valued Radon Measures, *Memoirs. of AMS*, **139**, American Mathematical Society, Providence, 1974.

The sequence $(\sum_{k=1}^n f_k\cdot x_k)$ is Cauchy in $\mathcal{P}$ because $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is absolutely summable, yet it is not convergent as there is no function $F$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int\limits_A \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(t)\cdot x_k\,{\rm d}t\to \int_A F(t)\,{\rm d}t.$$

It seems to me that Pettis integrable functions form a closed subspace of the space of Dunford integrable functions, hence you may extend the above result as in the case where $X$ is infinite-dimensional, you have an incomplete, closed subspace of a normed space, so the space itself cannot be complete.

*Addendum*. Let me point out that if you want to do some functional analysis with the space of Pettis integrable functions, even though incomplete, it is [barrelled](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1992-114-03/S0002-9939-1992-1107271-2/S0002-9939-1992-1107271-2.pdf).

Comment: Do you know a reference to check that $L_1(\mu)\odot_{\varepsilon}X$ is complete if and only if $X$ is finite-dimensional. Anyways, thanks a lot for your help. I had been thinking for a while if those two spaces were complete.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are infinite-dimensional Banach spaces and $\alpha$ is any reasonable crossnorm, then $X\odot_\alpha Y$ is incomplete. Choose two sequences of norm-one, linearly independent vectors $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Show that $(\sum_{k=1}^n \tfrac{1}{k^2}x_k\otimes y_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence without a limit in  $X\odot_\alpha Y$.